# Why can't I have early returns in Solidjs?

Tags: solid-js

I've just started with Solidjs (coming from React) and I have encountered some strange behaviour. When I have multiple returns, global state is not working. In the case below:

```js
const Test = () => { 
  const [user, setUser] = useUserContext()

  if (!user()) return null
  return ( 
    <div> 
      <div>
      {user()? user()?.username : "No user"}  
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

if the user is set from another component, this component still returns null (the user is null initially). But if I move that if logic inside the last return (i.e. have only one return), then it works. Why is this happening?

Could not find any resources where this behaviour was mentioned.

Comment: You're returning nothing (`null`) if the initial value of `user()` is empty. That is checked only once, when `Test()` executed, and means it'll *never* render anything. You'll have to return a signal instead, where the signal value is either `null` or that div with the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early returns do not work for SolidJS components because components are executed once when they are loaded. Unlike React, there is no component level re-rendering in SolidJS.

You can use expression like ternary operator or use built-in components like `Show` or `Switch`/`Match` for conditional rendering.

```js
const Test = () => { 
  const [user, setUser] = useUserContext();
  return user() ? <div>{user()?.username}</div>: <div>No User</div>;
}
```

User is guaranteed to exist inside `Show` component, so that, we can use non-null assertion for performance:

```js
const Test = () => { 
  const [user, setUser] = useUserContext();
  return ( 
    <Show when={user()} fallback={<div>No User</div>}> 
      <div>{user()!.username}</div>
    </Show>
  )
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap the component in a memo, so that force re-rendering using the memoized value.

```js
const Test = createMemo(() => { 
  const [user, setUser] = useUserContext()

  if (!user()) return null
  return ( 
    <div> 
      <div>
      {user()? user()?.username : "No user"}  
      </div>
    </div>
  )
});
```